# How to show a yaml file content in a table with filename in the header section of the table using in LINUX commandline

Tags: shell, view, yaml, cat

I would like to customize my bash/zsh in such a way so that when I cat (view) a yaml file it shows the content in a table with filename in the header section in it using in LINUX command line. I am referring to the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The cat clone [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) would exactly do that when fed with a .yaml file.

If you setup an alias `alias cat=bat` (eg. in your `.bashrc`) then calling cat would have the same behaviour.